# Change view properties depending on size class

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

I am designing two layouts for a view controller, using two size classes.
For some of the views, there are a few properties that I wanted to have different values depending on the size class.

For instance, there is a Label that I need to be centre-aligned in one size class, but right-aligned in the other; A view's background should have an alpha/translucency value in one class, and another value in the other class.

However it looks like these properties cannot be set taking account the size class I am currently editing. If I change it in one class, it will reflect in the others too.

Is there a proper way, or maybe a workaround (programmatically?) that allows me to set different values for distinct classes?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the only things you can change in the IB based on size classes are which views are in the hierarchy, their sizes/positions, and text fonts.

You can check the size class programmatically in your view controller with `self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass` and `self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass` and change the view properties based on the values.

You would also want to implement `willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:` to handle possible changes in size class after the view appears.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically by checking the `bounds` value of the screen and applying changes accordingly:

```
       if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 768 {
            // iPad, which corresponds to the regular class
            myImage.alpha = 1.0
        } else {
            // Every iPhone model, which is the compact class
            myImage.alpha = 0.5
        }
```

Or even more precisely:

```
        if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 480 {
            // iPhone 4
        } else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 568 {
            // iPhone 5
        } else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 375 {
            // iPhone 6
        } else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 414 {
            // iPhone 6+
        } else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 768 {
            // iPad
        }
```